# Efficient way of populating 300+ DIVs with HTML data from a JSON callback?

Tags: jquery

I have a script that takes 18 seconds to complete because it's populating about 300 DIVs with HTML data. Code below:

HTML:

```
    <div id="window">
        <div id="wall">
            <div class="module">
                <div>
                    <div class="face front"></div>
                    <div class="face back"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Javascript:

```
for (i = 0; i < numModules-1; ++ i)
{
    var $mod = $('.module:eq(0)').clone();

    modLeft += modSize;
    if (modLeft + modSize > $('#wall').width())
    {
        modLeft = 0;
        modTop += modSize;
    }
    $mod.css({
        left: modLeft,
        top: modTop
    }).appendTo('#wall');
}

$.getJSON('html_server.php?callback=?', function(data) {
    var htmlCount = data.length;

    for (i = 0; i < numModules /* 300 or more */; ++ i)
    {
        var pick = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(htmlCount/2)) * 2;
        var contentFront = data[pick];
        var contentBack = data[pick+1];
        var modStyle = '';
        var $mod = $('.module:eq(' + i + ')');
        var $modFront = $mod.find('.front');
        var $modBack = $mod.find('.back');

        // Set HTML content on front & back of module
        $modFront.html(contentFront);
        $modBack.html(contentBack);
    }
});
```

If I comment out the two `.html()` calls, run time drops to about 110ms, so those are clearly the culprits. And the HTML content is not a ton, maybe 300 bytes of data at most.

Any advice?

EDIT: Added code that creates the DIVs. Perhaps I could move that within the getJSON callback and just drop in the HTML as they're created? Would that help?

Comment: can we see your html?    there are a lot of ways to optimize this, but the best one would be to take whatever is holding all your divs, detach it,  edit it as a javascript object, and then do 1 .html after it's all done.  not knowing your html structure will make that tricky to write out though :)

Comment: @CaptSaltyJack -> How is `.front` and `.back` inside `.module`? That way you can build .module string/array inside the for..loop and push them to #wall outside the loop.

Comment: I think what you guys are suggesting is to build the HTML first, then append in one shot. The problem is, as you can see in the code above, I need to explicitly set CSS positioning on each one, so using `$mod.css()` is handy. Is there some other way to do this other than just building a raw string like `<div class="module" style="left: 200px; top: 200px"></div>`?

Comment: When using JS to change style, the style tag is just appended on. When building the markup in a loop, just adding the style tag yourself will probably be faster and simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created `module` as a template and replaced the content with the response. And Moved your html logic below the JSON so it can done once. See below,

```
 var modTmpl = '<div class="module"><div><div class="face front">{CONTENT_FRONT}</div><div class="face back">{CONTENT_BACK}</div></div></div>';

$.getJSON('html_server.php?callback=?', function(data) {
    var htmlCount = data.length;

    var pick, tmp, $mods = [];
    for (i = 0; i < numModules /* 300 or more */; ++ i)
    {
        pick = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(htmlCount/2)) * 2;
        tmp = modTmpl
                .replace(/{CONTENT_FRONT}/, data[pick])
                .replace(/{CONTENT_BACK}/, data[pick+1]);
        $mods.push(tmp);
    }
});

/*
    I am leaving the below code untouched as it seems like you are 
    positioning each module. If not then you can just 
    $('#wall').append($mods.join('')); and remove below for loop
*/
for (i = 0; i < numModules-1; ++ i)
{
    var $mod = $mods[i]; //use the pushed modules and append now

    modLeft += modSize;
    if (modLeft + modSize > $('#wall').width())
    {
        modLeft = 0;
        modTop += modSize;
    }
    $mod.css({
        left: modLeft,
        top: modTop
    }).appendTo('#wall');
}
```

Comment: @CaptSaltyJack This could have been answered long ago if only you had posted that HTML :P

Comment: Good answer +1, as a sidenote jQuery once had a [tmlp()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.tmpl/) function, never seemed to go anywhere but could have been useful for this? Not crazy about the use of regex, or the fact that it still appends each module seperately, and will be almost as slow as the original?

Comment: @adeneo Thanks.. yea.. that had a lot more features than a simple string replace and it is beta for a looong time.. There are other better plugin out there for templates.. http://dev.af83.com/2010/09/15/jquery-mustache-more-than-just-a-jquery-plugin.html

Comment: tmpl is a beta, and won't ever be anything else, but it's solid for what it does. i use it in a large scale production app with no problem at all.

Comment: @Vega - side note: you meant to not use 'var' with $mods, correct? Doing so would scope it within the anonymous callback and it would not be usable outside that scope?

Comment: This doesn't work. It doesn't like `$mod.css()`. I don't think you can do `var $mod = $mods[i]` because you're just setting `$mod` equal to a string containing HTML, not an actual jQuery object.

Comment: @Vega - tried changing it to `$mods.push($(tmp))` to no avail.

Comment: @CaptSaltyJack You don't need `$(tmp)` and for `$mod.css` can you try using `$($mod)`. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: @Vega - so one hitch.. that for loop needs to be moved within the `$.getJSON()` call. I kept wondering why '$mods' was empty. :) The code works, but is still slow due to the loop and calling `$.append()` over and over. But I need to individually position each module somehow. I'll figure it out. Probably just use inline style in the HTML.

Comment: @CaptSaltyJack `$('#wall').append($mods.join(''));` is the correct way to go. As you have mentioned, If we append inside the loop, then we are still making that many DOM updates which is slower. You can post a new question about positioning with a possible DEMO in jsFiddle. It should be doable.

Comment: @Vega Wow, how sad. Even a single call to your suggestion above (outside the loop) causes an 8-second delay. I'm going to have to research alternate ideas. But thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to tell without seeing the actual markup, but is should probably look something like:

```
$.getJSON('html_server.php?callback=?', function(data) {
    var mod='';
    for (i = 0; i < numModules /* 300 or more */; ++ i) {
        var pick = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(data.length/2)) * 2;
            mod += '<div class="module'>;
            mod += '<div class="front">'+data[pick]+'</div>');
            mod += '<div class="back">'+data[pick+1]+'</div>');
            mod += '</div>';
    }
    $('#someParent').html(mod);
});
```

Building everything in JS, and inserting into the DOM only once is the way to go here, but it will have to be built according to the actual markup, the above is just a generic example of how to do it.

Comment: Again please read his code before you move it outside.. $modFront and $modBack are local var and they may be a specific section.. Even after you define them outside, As per you code it is going to add them all to the last section.

Comment: Just realised that as I posted, changed it, but will change it again, just need to add a way to create the object in JS.

Comment: This is probably the way to go. I'm adjusting my code a bit and testing this out.. basically instead of using my first loop to `.clone()` one mod, I'll create all the DIVs there out of raw HTML like @adeneo suggests.

Comment: Creating the html in JS should'nt take long at all, it's the inserting and lookups in the DOM that takes time, and inserting only once is going to be way faster than doing it three hundred times.

Answer (score -1):

I'd create these a bunch at a time (say in groups of 20) on a `setTimeout` device with a small delay value - it might not be any faster to finish, but it won't lock the browser out whilst it is processing. The perceived start-up speed may therefore be faster. You could switch on an AJAX spinner or similar whilst it is loading - and allow your user to interact immediately whilst it is rendering.

Comment: It needs to be faster. Locking up is not the problem.